# What are the reserved attributes in Elixir?

Tags: elixir, keyword

I just spent a lot of time investigating why my code was returning nil:

```
defmodule Test
  @impl 42
  def foo, do: IO.inspect(@impl)
```

It turns out that `@impl` is a reserved attribute name. Okay, lesson learned. However, now I am wondering what the full list of reserved attribute keywords are? I can't find the documentation. The closest I found was [this](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/module-attributes.html)

> Elixir has a handful of reserved attributes. Here are a few of them,
>   the most commonly used ones:
>
> ```
> @moduledoc - provides documentation for the current module.
> @doc - provides documentation for the function or macro that follows the attribute.
> @behaviour - (notice the British spelling) used for specifying an OTP or user-defined behaviour.
> @before_compile - provides a hook that will be invoked before the module is compiled. This makes it possible to inject functions inside
> ```
>
> the module exactly before compilation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the documentation for module `Module` from std lib.

https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Module.html#module-module-attributes